# How to fix request method type when sending $_GET in form field

Tags: php

I have some code like this:

```
<form method="post" action="req.php">
   <input type="text" name="somthing">
   <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
</form>

<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
echo $method;
```

Without submission It prints `GET`, After Submission It prints `POST`, *But*, when I fill the text field with text that contains (`$_GET`), it redirects to `index.php` and in another code like this it prints `GET`!

[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmMTm.png)

Comment: Forms are automatically send with `$_POST`, and loading a webpage is automatically done over `$_GET` -- this is the expected result. I'm not quite sure what your question is? Are you asking why `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is `GET` when your form submission contains the string `$_GET`?

Comment: nothing in the code does any redirecting, so there's something we can't see going on if your ending up on index.php

Comment: Redirects are always processed using `GET`. But I don't see anything here that causes a redirect.

Comment: Yes, that is the question, and sometimes redirect to index page

Comment: Maybe you have a rewrite rule on the server that's doing it?

Comment: @Barmar , Yes ,no thing cause the redirection but it's redirect when text field contains the string "$_GET" or "$_POST", "$_SESSION"

Comment: @Barmar No I didn't use any rewrite rules.

Comment: I removed the index.php then this is the result when text field contains ($_GET) 
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /t/req.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: I copied your script to my server, I can't reproduce the problem.